# Operating system memory management, seg-fault?

Tags: c, memory-management, operating-system

I am implementing my own `malloc` function called `kalloc`.

But I am getting segmentation fault. I have set memory size to 100.
`int _size = 4` right now but segmentation fault happens at 3rd loop in `main()`.

```
void* kalloc(int _size) {
    void* ptr = NULL;  
    struct ListNode* freeMem = kallocator.free_memory;
    struct ListNode* allocMem = kallocator.allocated_memory;
    struct KBlock* freeBlock;
    freeBlock = freeMem->item;
    struct KBlock* allocBlock = (struct KBlock*) malloc(sizeof(struct KBlock));
    if(kallocator.aalgorithm == FIRST_FIT){
        while(freeMem){
            if(freeBlock->size >= _size){
                allocBlock->size = _size;
                allocBlock->address = freeBlock->address;
                struct ListNode* listnode = List_createNode(allocBlock);
                List_insertTail(&allocMem, listnode);
                printf("size of freeBlock: %d\n", freeBlock->size);
                printf("address of freeBlock: %p\n", freeBlock->address);
                ptr = freeBlock->address;
                printf("Pointer value: %p\n", ptr);
                freeBlock->address = freeBlock->address + _size;
                allocMem = allocMem->next;
                freeBlock->size = freeBlock->size - _size;
                printf("allocBlock size: %d\n", allocBlock->size);
            }
            else{
                printf("Not enough space in memory\n");
                return NULL;
            }
            freeMem = freeMem->next;
        }

    }
    else if(kallocator.aalgorithm == BEST_FIT){

    }
    else if(kallocator.aalgorithm == WORST_FIT){

    }
    else{
        printf("No algorithm chosen\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    // Allocate memory from kallocator.memory 
    // ptr = address of allocated memory
    return ptr;
}
```

Please help me figure out why `seg fault` happens.

Comment: Can you put together a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem? Which 3rd loop in main? There's no main function in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Pls try gdb to trace where seg fault is happening. Assuming you are on Linux/unix, compile code with options (if compiler is gcc)

```
gcc -ggdb -g3 <.c file> -o <progname>
```

Execute progname with gdb as

```
gdb <progname>
```

At gdb prompt

```
gdb> run
```

On segfault gdb prompt will show where you check backtrack as

```
gdb> bt
```

It will show line number where segfault has happened along with function call stack (frames with number)
For values of variables or pointers to check use gdb print command

```
gdb> p <varnams>
```

To check in particular function in call stack go to that stack frame as

```
gdb> frame <frame number>
```